# Is there a good way to identify which building:part belongs to which building in an osm file

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

I'm trying to create 3D buildings out of osm-data and put them on a toposurface. Is there a good way to identify which building/building:part are belong together.

I'm using OSMSharp to parse the osm file but I didn't find a way to check which building/building:part belongs together.

Comment: Is there a good way to .. . Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The established tagging standard for 3D buildings in OSM is called ["Simple 3D Buildings"](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings) (S3DB).

According to this standard, there are two valid cases:

- If there is a type=building relation, all of the building's parts must be members of it.
- Any building:part area which is not a member of such a relation must be geometrically contained within exactly one building outline and will belong to that building.

So for data mapped according to the standard, there should be no guessing involved. How applications should behave for incorrect data is undefined, though. (Somewhat common errors include building parts which overlap a building outline, but aren't entirely contained in it, and buildings which aren't entirely decomposed into parts.)

Contrary to what's stated in the answer by scai, building relations are *not* something that should always exist – they are as of 2019 only required by S3DB in complex cases which would otherwise be ambiguous. Nor can you rely on them to exist in practice, as 90% of building parts are not members of a relation: There are [1M building:part elements](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building%3Apart), but just [100k part memberships](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/relations/building#roles) in relations. Also, there are no further requirements in place, such as a need for building:part areas to share nodes with their building outline. (Although if you're only looking for a quick hack, that might be "good enough" to get off the ground.)

Answer (score -1):

All *ways* of a building tagged as `building:part` should be contained in a *relation* of `type=building` according to the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building:part). An example of such a relation is [relation 9533751](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/9533751).

If such a relation doesn't exist then you can only guess. A good start is to assume that all `building:part` ways that share at least one *node* do belong together.

Comment: Ok. This is a good start, but there are much more parts in the osm data then in the relation as you can see on this example.

Relation: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/298750
Click on the building to the all the building:parts:
https://osmbuildings.org/?lat=53.55083&lon=10.00803&zoom=18.0&tilt=30

Somehow OSMBuildings identified all the building:parts. And not all of them share ways. How did they do it?

Comment: Can you point to a part that doesn't share nodes with the building ways? With a (quick) check I could find only parts that share nodes with building ways. Apart from sharing nodes you could also use a "is_in" query to identify building parts located inside a building.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, your right. I looked at the wrong ways. They all share nodes.
The solution is fine.